# Contenteditable inside Polymer element

Tags: polymer, contenteditable, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I´m trying to make a custom polymer element be `contenteditable`. I´m a polymer newbie so I´m probably doing something stupid. I can create the element and it renders and reacts to events but it does not go into editable mode when clicked. Any ideas?

```
<polymer-element name="editable-h1">
  <template>
    <h1 contenteditable="true">
      <content></content>
    </h1>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

[Example on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/mikaelharsjo/pen/bNGZwx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements declared within custom tag are considered part of the light DOM, and I'm guessing that, due to shadow boundaries, there is a problem with using `contenteditable` on them. You would need to reinsert the content nodes into the shadow root of your custom element to make this work.

Here is an example of how you can accomplish that:

### Codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbNWdw

### Source

```
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-tooltip/core-tooltip.html">

<polymer-element name="editable-h1">
  <script>
  Polymer('editable-h1', {
    ready: function() {
        var sroot = this.$;
        var nodes = sroot.mycontent.getDistributedNodes();
        [].forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
            sroot.editableportion.appendChild(node);
        });
    },
    blur: function () {
      console.log('blur');
    },
    click: function () {
      console.log('click');
    },
    focus: function () {
      console.log('focus');
    }
  });
  </script>
  <template>
    <h1 contenteditable="true" on-click="{{click}}" on-blur="{{blur}}" on-focus={{focus}} id="editableportion">
    </h1>
    <content id="mycontent"></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

</head>
  <body>
    <h1 contenteditable="true">I´m a regular heading</h1>    
    <editable-h1>
      I'm an polymer enhanced heading
      <span>With a span for good measure</span>
    </editable-h1> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Sweet! Works great. Do you know if this is expected behaviour or will it change?